# Probability theory. Time interval

Tags: probability-theory

If the time interval between two power surges is less than **a** seconds, then the refrigerator breaks down with a terrible bang. Find the probability of a refrigerator failure in **T** seconds, if during this time there were only two power surges.

I tried to depict this task in the picture. Black segment - time **T**. Red - time interval between two power surges, designated it as **b**.
That is, if **b < a**, then the refrigerator breaks down with a bang.

I drew, but I can not bring to mind. What can you suggest?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adsXG.jpg)

Comment: There is a known distribution for the times events occur in a Poisson process in a given interval, conditioned on the exact number of events in that interval. The distribution surprisingly doesn't depend on the rate parameter of the Poisson process. When there's just one event it's uniform. Do you know what happens when there are two events?

Comment: @Ian I'm afraid that I don't know

Comment: Did you know the thing about the one event case? If you know how to look that up then you can find the two event case probably.

Comment: @lan I don't quite understand one event case